# Electrical equivalent of inverted pendulum

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, oscillators, signal-processing

***Background***

I am working on a summer project to design labs for undergraduate students. One of the topics is feedback and there is already quite a lot of stuff about passive feedback, so we might add some active feedback stuff. One really cool active feedback process is **balancing the inverted pendulum** (e.g. like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWJHcI7UcuE)). I would like to create something like this, but purely electrical, because motors and mechanical parts are more expensive and cheap ones tend to jam quite easily (cheap enough for the labs is very cheap...).

***What makes the inverted pendulum cool***

So what we are looking for is an **intrinsically unstable electrical configuration that needs to be actively adjusted** (e.g. by a voltage from a programmable chip). Now one could e.g. think of a charged capacitor. It would discharge unless "balanced". But the balancing here is trivial, one just puts a voltage on and it becomes stable. In the mechanical analogy this would be just fixing the rotation axis in place. So another condition is that this "electrical pendulum" is **unstable at all times** like in the video and some parameter (e.g. a voltage) has to be adjusted constantly to keep it stable.

So the question is: ***Is there an electrical equivalent of this inverted pendulum balancing process?***

Comment: What is [tag:feedback] meant for?

Comment: maybe a tunnel diode (negative resistance) oscillator that is driven by active bias to prevent  its oscillation.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 For this :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback#Types

Comment: @Numrok: I mean define the tag; compose the tag wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the paper linked to in sammy's answer does provide an equivalent circuit (page 5988), it seems of little practical use, since even in (unstable) equilibrium the current in L2 rises linearly with time. Within seconds (at most) it will reach a limit: saturation of the transformer core or maximum current (either I=U/R where R is the resistance of the transformer winding, or the power supply's maximum output current)

Apart from a NTC thermistor at some temperature above ambient (with the voltage constant, when temperature goes up resistance goes down, increasing the current and dissipated power, further increasing temperature; when temperature goes down, power drops, the NTC cools down further), I can't think of a solution with only passive components. With active components, an inherently unstable circuit is easy to make. The small angle approximation of a pendulum is equivalent to a mass on a spring, and an inverted one is equivalent to a spring with negative spring constant (F=-kx; with negative k, the force is in the direction of the displacement).

With that approximation, the equation for the pendulum becomes ${d^2\theta\over dt^2}={g\over \ell}\theta$

This can be simulated with two [opamp integrator circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Op_amp_integrator):

The output of an integrator is $u_{\text{out}} = -\frac{1}{RC}\int_0^t u_{\text{in}}\, dt$

First integrator: With RC=1, if $u_{\text{in}}$ represents the angular acceleration, $-u_{\text{out}}$ will be the angular velocity.

Second integrator: With $RC={\ell\over g}$ , if $-u_{\text{in}}$ represents the angular velocity, $u_{\text{out}}$ will be $g\over \ell$ times the angular displacement.

With the output of the first integrator connected to the input of the second one and vice versa, the circuit will behave like the inverted pendulum (at small angles). It is inherently unstable and input offset voltage present in any real opamp will start it off. The voltage at the non-inverting input (+) of the first opamp (in a normal integrator circuit connected to the ground) represents the position of the pivot point, and balancing the pendulum can be done by adjusting that voltage. Note that dual supply opamps and a symmetric power supply are required to allow negative output voltage, since the pendulum must be able to swing both ways (no pun intended).

Comment: Wonderful idea. I am thinking is it possible to model with the inductor and the capacitor only...

Answer (score 2):

The following paper is devoted to electrical analogues to mechanical oscillators.  Fig. 6 illustrates a simple coupled LC circuit which imitates the inverted pendulum on a cart given in Fig. 5.  It does not include a circuit to balance the 'pendulum' as in the video.

https://core.ac.uk/download/files/508/12941830.pdf

I also found the following which may be useful.  With much less mathematics than the above paper it shows how to construct electrical circuits which are analogs of mechanical systems.

http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Analogs/ElectricalMechanicalAnalogs.html

Comment: Isn't this sentence similar for you? *I found the paper by googling your exact title* http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266264/why-do-we-not-see-stars-during-the-day

Comment: @lucas : Yes it is.  Would you prefer that I use different words when making the same point with other users?

Comment: No I mean you downvoted my question because of this reason. But now you earned 25 reputation for a similar question and didn't downvote it. And so I should think about meaning of *taking personally* because my English is terrible!

Comment: In addition, this is not an answer, this should be a comment. But I think comments doesn't have reputation!

Comment: @sammygerbil thanks for your answer, I guess I should improve my googeling ;)

Comment: @lucas : Like everyone I am not always consistent in my voting, but I never down-vote for such personal reasons, certainly not for poor English.  No, this is an answer to the title, asking for an electrical equivalent of the inverted pendulum.  My comment about how easy the search was *is* a comment, so I will re-post it as a comment - just to please you!

Comment: @Numrok : By the way, I found the paper by googling your exact title.  Your question above was #1 in the search list, this paper was #2.  For the 2nd article I changed "equivalent" to "analog".  This was #7 again on p.1.  Yes, it was that easy!

Comment: I don't mean you downvoted my question because of my poor English. I mean you downvote my posts because you have not forgotten our past argument while you said to me that you didn't take it personally.

Comment: @lucas : Should we continue this discussion in the chatroom?

Comment: yes, Of course!